# Get param from returned URL

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I want to parse the result from GET request using this typescript:

```
return this.httpClient
      .get('http://localhost:8080', options)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Response) => {
          console.log(response)
        })
      );
```

I want to get the `code` value from the redirected http response: `http://localhost:9000/callback?code=7CLwgh`. How I can get the value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use split string

```
var str="http://localhost:9000/callback?code=7CLwgh";
var sp=str.split("code=");
console.log(sp[1]);
```